# Unable to read Select Energy meter MFM 384 C

Tags: modbus, energy, rs485

A trying to read selec mfm384 c energy meter using modbus RTU protocol in terminal software (Docklight), am getting some irrelevant response starting with 3F...... it need to respond with Slave address in its first byte, how ever CRC is also getting failed,Can you help me in explaining command and response formats in selec mfm 384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :  I have 2 Wire RS 485 from energy meter and i have always (Even while energy meter is responding through Rx+ and Rx- lines )enabled Tx+ and Tx- , Which caused corruption of transmitted data from energy meter